# calling glClearColor and glClear without attaching any shader and program

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL ES 2.0, do I have to attach and use any shader and program if I only want to clear the color buffers?

If I call `glCLearColor`, `glCLear`, and then `eglSwapBuffers`, what will happen? I didn't find this information in the spec. My code sequence is:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
eglDisp = eglGetCurrentDisplay();
eglSurface = eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL_DRAW);
eglSwapBuffers ( eglDisp, eglSurface );
```

Or is this not described in the spec, and it depends on the OpenGL driver and the GPU itself?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shader program for `glClear()`. The clearest statement I could find in the ES 2.0 spec is this, from section "2.10 Vertex Shaders", on page 31:

> If UseProgram is called with program set to zero, then the current rendering state refers to an invalid program object, and the results of vertex and fragment shader execution due to any DrawArrays or DrawElements commands are undeﬁned. However, this is not an error.

Since `glClear()` does not use a vertex or fragment shader, and having 0 as the active program is explicitly **not** an error, calling `glClear()` without an active program is completely valid.